# pyqt window not responding while running program

Tags: download, pyqt, no-response

I am trying to download image through web scrapping through gui, whenever i run script images are downloaded but gui window doesnt respond and keep loading and after all images are downloaded it gets its control back plus my search button completely get frozen once i click it and it start to download images

**index.py**

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QWidget,
    QMainWindow,
    QLineEdit,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QPushButton,
    QGridLayout,
    QLabel
)
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtGui import QCursor
import sys
from IMD import Parser
from pathlib import Path
import os

os.chdir("./images")

class ImageDownloaderWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Layout")

        self.window = QWidget()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignTop)
        self.window.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.setFixedSize(550, 500)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.window)

        self.createText("Image Downloader", self.layout, """
            margin: 80px 20px 10px 20px;
            font-size: 40px;
            font-family: monospace;
            font-weight: bold;
        """)
        self.createText("Download Images of your choice", self.layout, """
            margin-bottom: 80px;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-family: 'Eras Bold ITC';
        """)
        self.name = ""

        self.createSearchBar()
        self.createSearchButton()
        self.searchClickEvent()

    def createText(self, text, layout, stylesheet=None):
        self.display = QLabel(text)
        self.display.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
        self.display.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignHCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.display)


    def createSearchBar(self):
        self.searchBar = QLineEdit()
        # self.searchBar.setStyleSheet("margin: 0px 50px; color: #fff;")
        self.searchBar.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.searchBar)

    def createSearchButton(self):
        self.searchButton = QPushButton("Search")
        self.searchButton.setFixedSize(140, 60)
        self.searchButton.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.CursorShape.PointingHandCursor))
        self.layout.addWidget(self.searchButton, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        
    def displayImageName(self):
        return self.searchBar.text()

    def searchClickEvent(self):
        self.searchButton.clicked.connect(self.parsedImages)

    def parsedImages(self):
        self.name = self.displayImageName()
        parser = Parser("https://unsplash.com/s/photos/"+self.name)
        Path(self.name).mkdir(exist_ok=True)
        parser.getSources()
        os.chdir(self.name)
        imgsLen = len(os.listdir())

        images = parser.srcs

        for index, img in enumerate(images):
            with open(self.name+str(index)+'.jpg', "wb") as f:
                f.write(parser.getContent(img))

def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    app.setStyleSheet(
        """
            QWidget {
                color: #fff;
                background-color: #123;
            }
            
            QLineEdit {
                color: #000;
                padding: 10px;
                border: 1px solid #000;
                border-radius: 10px;
                background-color: #fff;
                margin: 0px 50px;
                font-size: 15pt;
            }
            
            QPushButton {
                background-color: #00a656;
                margin-top: 10px;
                padding: 250px;
                border: 1px solid #00a656;
                border-radius: 10px;
                font-size: 23px;
                font-weight: bold;
                letter-spacing: 3px;
            }
            
            QPushButton:hover {
                cursor: pointer;
                background-color: #000;
                color: #fff;
            }
        """
    )

    ui = ImageDownloaderWindow()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

also i have made my own parser class to get image of content
**#parser.py**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pathlib import Path
import os

class Parser:
    def __init__(self, site):
        self.site = site
        self.srcs = []

    def parse_content(self):
        soup = None
        try:
            response = requests.get(self.site)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        except Exception as error:
            soup = None
            print(error)
        finally:
            return soup

    def getSources(self):
        siteContent = self.parse_content()
        if siteContent:
            imgElements = siteContent.find_all("img", class_="YVj9w")
            for img in imgElements:
                self.srcs.append(img.get("src"))
            return True
        return False

    def getContent(self, img):
        response = requests.get(img)
        return response.content
```

how should i make my gui window and betton working when it is downloading image. I quit tkinter because i faced same issue there and i thought there was problem with tkinter but now i knew gui behaves in such way and it may have some solution.

Comment: You either move the parsing to a QThread and use custom signal to communicate with the UI, or use QNetworkAccessManager.